# Install 2 PCIe NVMe SSDs in same pc

Tags: ssd, motherboard, pci-express, nvme

Am trying to install two PCIe NVMes in my pc with this pcie adapter ([aliexpress pcie adapter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000619345349.html)) with second GPU PCIe slot. When I install both devices only one device (which is installed on motherboard's PCIe NVMe slot) appear in UEFI settings storage section. But once I removed it, the second NVMe appears in the UEFI settings. Is it possible to install two PCIe SSDs and use on same PC..? Or am I doing it wrong.? My motherboard is **[AsRock AB350 Pro 4](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/AB350%20Pro4/index.asp#Specification)**. Main NVMe **Samsung 980 PRO 500GB**, The second one is **Samsung SM981 256GB**.

Comment: Your motherboard needs to provide two separate M.2 sockets for two NVMe drives. My own desktop provides 1 M.2 socket and I just added a 2TB Samsung SATA SSD as the second drive. Works fine and is very fast.

Comment: Actually am trying to install two PCIe SSDs not PCIe NVMe + SATA M.2.. :) .. Did you see that PCIe adapter I've linked..?

Comment: @Pumayk26 - Are you plugging in the adapter in the PCIe slot that is disabled if the NVMe M.2 slot is used on your motherboard? You can check the manual for more information on that particular limitation

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is your Motherboard itself. Your CPU has a limited amount of PCIe lanes that it can use to connect to devices. Your Motherboard has a limited number of PCIe lanes that it can allocate as well. The reason why the PCIe card only appears when you take the original SSD out is a result of lack of PCIe lanes. I am unsure of your CPU, but looking at the motherboard specs I am going to guess that your issue is the CPU not having enough PCIe lanes available to it. Upgrading you CPU would likely solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

CPUs and chipsets have a limited number of PCIe ports, each of which has a limited number of lanes. Some devices have reconfigurable ports, which can be used as either a single larger port, or a collection of smaller ports but not all ports are reconfigurable in this way. Some motherboards have signal switches to allow the ports to be used for multiple different functions.

Adding to the complexity, some CPU vendors have started to use number of PCIe lanes as a market segmentation feature. This leads to difficult decisions for motherboard designers, trying to find the best compromise between support for different CPUs.

The motherboard manual says

> 1 x Ultra M.2 Socket (M2_1), supports type 2242/2260/2280
> M.2 PCI Express module up to Gen3 x4 (32 Gb/s) (with Ryzen
> CPU) or Gen3 x2 (16 Gb/s) (with A-Series APU)**
> ** If M2_1 is occupied, PCIE4 will be disabled

Which is not clear as to whether the footnote about disabling of PCIE4 applies to all processors, or only to A-Series APUs.

In any case that seems to be what is happening. PCIE4 on your board is the "second GPU PCIe slot" (PCIE2 is the main GPU PCIe slot, PCIE1, PCIE3, PCIE5 and PCIE6 are the x1 slots) and does indeed seem to be disabled when plugging in a M.2 SSD.

If you just want more storage and aren't so bothered about speed, you could almost certainly put the second NVME SSD in one of your x1 slots. You will need a different adapter for this as the x4 adapter won't fit in the x1 slots. These adapters used to be hard to find but they seem to have become more common recently.